# Javascript | How to add an element to an array every n elements starting from index x?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Audi", "Nissan", "Ford"];
```

I want to add another element `"Triumph"` every 2 elements starting from index 2 to give me this

```
cars
["Saab", "Volvo", "Triumph", "BMW", "Audi", "Triumph", "Nissan", "Ford", "Triumph"];
```

I have tried this:

```
for (let [index, val] of cars.entries()) {
    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        cars.splice(index, 0, "")
    }
}
```

but it adds a new element every other element not every 2 and I'm not sure how to make it start from a particular index

`[ '', 'Saab', '', 'Volvo', '', 'BMW', '', 'Audi', '', 'Nissan', '', 'Ford']`

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We don’t appreciate “I want”-type of questions here. Show us what you have tried, or at least explain what your thought process about how this could perhaps be done was so far.

Comment: I have added my attempt

Comment: change index % 2 to index % 3

Comment: simple! thanks guys

Comment: @imlearningcode FYI, the reason this performs different than expected is due to the fact that if you splice an element into the array, the other elements (that still need iteration) shift one position to the right. eg. When you're at the element `"foo"` in `["foo", "bar"]`. After you insert the new element the array looks like `["new", "foo", "bar"]`. Iterating further over the array the next element will be `"foo"` again.

Comment: @3limin4t0r that makes sense, thanks for the deeper explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a reverse iteration so you're not modifying the same array you're iterating through, as this will alter the indexes.

Additionally, you might want to implement a simple edge-case to determine if you'll need to add a string to the end of the array. This can be done by seeing if the array itself is divisible by the amount of items you want to skip.

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Audi", "Nissan", "Ford"];

const insertAfterN = (arr, n, str) => {
  let newArray = [...arr];
  const addToEnd = newArray.length % n === 0;

  for (let i = newArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i !== 0) newArray.splice(i, 0, str)

  if (addToEnd) newArray.push(str);
  return newArray;
}

//Insert <"Triumph"> into the <cars> array after every <2> items
const result = insertAfterN(cars, 2, "Triumph");
console.log( result );
```

If you wanted something a bit more concise, you could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Audi", "Nissan", "Ford"];

const insertAfterN = (arr, n, str) => {
  const addToEnd = arr.length % n === 0;
  const result = arr.reduce((a,i,idx) => { idx && !(idx%n) ? a.push(str,i) : a.push(i); return a; }, []);
  if (addToEnd) result.push(str);
  return result;
}

//Insert <"Triumph"> into the <cars> array after every <2> items
const result = insertAfterN(cars, 2, "Triumph");
console.log( result );
```